# matplotlib ticks overlapping with pre-existing ones

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to define ticks for a log scale axis, and a strange bug I am finding is that, on one axis only, the previous default ticks are not removed, and so my new custom ticks overlap them. But only on the y-axis.

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(np.linspace(15, 190), np.linspace(55, 310))
plt.xscale("log")
plt.xticks([2e1, 4e1, 6e1, 1e2, 2e2], [20, 40, 60, 100, 200])
plt.yscale("log")
plt.yticks([6e1, 1e2, 2e2, 3e2], [60, 100, 200, 300])
plt.show()
```

I believe I have treated the x axis and y axis identically, yet this method works for the x axis and the bug is evident on the y axis.

Thank you for advice in advance.

[image: resultant image here]

Comment: Perhaps try removing the ticks first, then change the scale and add new ones.

Comment: That is a good idea, but alas, no.
Passing ```plt.yticks([])``` before ```plt.yscale("log")``` does nothing as it appears setting the axis to log reinstates ticks, and passing ```plt.yticks([])``` after ```plt.yscale("log")``` only removes the tick at 100, presumably as does the next line setting the new ticks, so part of the same bug of not removing ticks.
Thanks for the suggestion though.
Looks like I have no option other than to move to Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it runs perfectly like this:

[image: screenshot]

- Matplotlib version: 3.2.1
- Python version: 3.7.7

Comment: Ok, thank you for testing and checking. I am on Python 2.7.14 and Matplotlib 2.2.3. Might be time I finally have to update :(

Comment: Updated to Python 3 and problem goes away. Now I just need to edit all my code...